# Can you recommend a book on wireless protocol design?

Tags: rf, radio, books

Can anyone recommend a book on wireless protocol design?

I'm trying to find books with a thorough treatment of MAC and network layers without just being a guide to one specific protocol.

The kinds of topics I'm looking for include: frequency hopping, time slicing, cryptography, low power design and routing.

Comment: *one* book? that's a *lot* of material to cover. :)

Comment: I can't say I have seen a single book that covers all of that. I have a book in my lab that covers frequency hopping and time slicing with a bit of low power and a separate book that covers routing. Can't say I have anything that covers cryptography, unless you are talking about using low level methods of disguising your transmission like DSSS.

Comment: Several books would do...

Comment: @Kellenjb By cryptography, I mean using symmetric and asymmetric ciphers to secure radio transmissions. Privacy and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

[Algorithms and Protocols for Wireless and Mobile Ad Hoc Networks](http://www.comsoc.org/content/algorithms-and-protocols-wireless-and-mobile-ad-hoc-networks)

Answer (score 0):

[Computer Networking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133499456) by Tannenbaum is a good guide to networking. It covers all the layers, but has plenty of info on the lower levels.

[Digital Communications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072957166) by Proakis is a great general guide to digital comms. Not sure it will be as specific as you'd like though.